# What is the purpose of clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects?

Tags: opengl, opencl

I did google for the question, and got from [this link](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects.html)

> clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects
>
> Acquire OpenCL memory objects that have been created from OpenGL objects.
>
> These objects need to be acquired before they can be used by any OpenCL commands queued to a command-queue.

I really don't understand why these objects **need to be acquired**. In my opinion, the reason of the acquiring is NOT OpenGL/OpenCL synchronization because the synchronization can be achieved by `glFinish` and `clFinish`.

I mean, if `clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects/clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects` are used, then `glFinish/clFinish` are redundant, and vice-versa.

Comment: If they are redundant for you, then use glFinish() and clFinish(). You will find out down the road that you get 10FPS only with a 20% GPU usage. Finish calls are blocking calls, that block all the pipeline, while acquires are non blocking. It is way better to use acquires, finish should never be used.

Comment: "It is way better to use acquires, finish should never be used."
It seems this is not correct, you can only do that if the extension cl_khr_gl_event is supported and enabled.

Comment: @Kata: If your implementation doesn't support a basic CL/GL interop extension like "cl_khr_gl_event", then you're probably not going to get reasonable interop performance anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean, if clEnqueueAcquireGLObjects/clEnqueueReleaseGLObjects are used, then glFinish/clFinish are redundant, and vice-versa.

You're thinking about this in entirely the wrong way.

`glFinish` causes OpenGL to perform a full CPU synchronization, such that the implementation will have completed all commands afterwards. `clFinish` does something similar for OpenCL.

The fact that you called one or the other has *absolutely no effect* on what a *different* system does. OpenGL has no idea that OpenCL exists, and vice-versa. `glFinish` has nothing to do with `clFinish` and vice-versa. So while OpenGL may have finished making some modification to an object, OpenCL has no idea that these modifications took place.

The purpose of acquiring and releasing OpenGL objects is for OpenCL and OpenGL to talk to one another. When objects are acquired, OpenCL tells OpenGL, "Hey, see these objects? They're *mine* now, so give them to me." This means that the OpenGL/OpenCL driver will do whatever mechanics are necessary to transfer access control over those objects to OpenCL.

For example, if an object has been paged out of GPU memory, OpenCL acquiring it may need to make it resident again. OpenCL and OpenGL have two separate sets of records that refer to this memory; by acquiring the object, you synchronize the OpenCL data with changes made by OpenGL. And so forth.

Notice that these mechanics have *nothing at all* to do with synchronizing GPU operations. They are about making the objects accessible to OpenCL.

If your OpenCL implementation doesn't have `cl_khr_gl_event`, then you must use OpenGL's synchronization mechanism to ensure that those objects are no longer in use before you acquire them. The two functions aren't redundant; they're doing different things to ensure the integrity of the system.